# What's going wrong with this sum?

Tags: summation

I'm using MMA 11.0.0 and I'm encountering this issue: I define

```
B[m_,n_]:=Binomial[m, n]/2^m
```

and then I do this sum:

```
f[m_, r_] = Sum[B[m,k]B[m-k,r-k],{k,0,r}]
```

which MMA evaluates as

> `((-3)^r 2^(-2 m) (-1 - m + r)!)/((-1 - m)! r!)`

but this cannot be right because (for instance)

```
f[4,3]
```

evaluates to

> `Indeterminate`

whereas

```
Sum[B[4,k]B[4-k,3-k],{k,0,3}]
```

evaluates to

> `27/64`

It doesn't seem to matter if I add Assumptions to the sum.  What's going on?

EDIT: In order to simplify the notation in this post, I used the symbol `k` in the sum. In my notebook, I'm using a symbol with a subscript and *that* seems to matter when I use the proper Assumptions!

Comment: Although the symbolic result returned cannot be used as is, it can be simplified a fair bit into `3^r 4^-m Binomial[m, r]`. (P.S., do not add the [tag:bugs] tag until your observed behavior has been confirmed to be a bug by other people or by Wolfram support.)

Comment: You should do `f[m_, r_] := Sum[B[m, k] B[m - k, r - k], {k, 0, r}]`, i.e. with `SetDelayed` (`:=`); then `f[4, 3]` yields `27/64`.

Comment: @corey979, sure but that's not the intended use: I wanted to have a valid closed-form expression for the sum. I ended up evaluating a few examples until I understood how it goes, but it's still weird that if one uses summation variables that have a subscript one can run into problems.

Comment: @Ziofil. In general, the use of `Subscript`s for anything other than display purposes is discouraged, exactly for reason like this; they don't behave as you think they should.

Comment: You don't show any code with subscripts. If that's your main issue you should edit the question so it adresses properly your issues. But keep in mind the [last comment of march](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128109/whats-going-wrong-with-this-sum?noredirect=1#comment346531_128109).

Comment: The closed-form result needs to be evaluated in the limit: `Limit[f[m, 3], m -> 4]` which evaluates to `27/64`